# Hyperlink to a filtered pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

Here's what I want to do.
I have a Pivot Table that contains data from more segments. Let's name them A, B, C and D.
I want to have an hyperlink that will open my pivot table directly showing just the data of segment A or B or C...
Is this possible?
If I want the hyperlink to a sheet with the selection on a specific cell it's easy... I do something like file.xls#sheet!cell but now I want to link it to the file and the sheet where the pivot table is and also to show just some data from that pivot (by default it shows all the data combined for A, B, C and D).

Comment: I don't think you can without VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyeperlinks are used to jump to locations, not to drive decisions. If you want to go to a particular customisable view of a pivotTable then you could either

1. Create multiple views of the same data with hyperlinks for each specific one
2. Run code to create a customisable view of a pivotTable when a button is clicked. Unless you can post detailed data for us to work on this is probably most easily resolved by you recording your own code with the macro recorder